# Unity button onclick don't fire function (linked through Unity interface)

Tags: unity-game-engine, button

I've a project in `Unity 2018.2.21f1`. I have already a `C#` script for handling coins in my game, called `CoinHandler`.

It already as a `gameobject` in the scene, and it has linked some components (`text`) that it has to update.

[image]
[image]

Then I've a `button` added to the scene (as you can see in the first picture), and I try to call a function from the previous script in his `on click()` event. For this, I go to the **inspector** and drag&drop the `coinHandler` gameObject, and select the desired function (method, since it returns `void`).

[image]

You may notice that the icon of the gameObject in this picture **changes** to the `script` icon. I don't know if this is a bad sign, but just notice it. It changes just after selecting the function. Before, it remains with its proper icon:

[image]

And finally, in the **console** I'm getting the next warning:

> No script asset for GameObjectSelectionItem. Check that the definition is in a file of the same name.

Of course, both name of the script and of the class inside it are the same.

I've [readed](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1505026/console-warning-no-script-asset-for-gameobjectsele.html) that this may be because of having the animator window open. I had, but I closed it, and everything was the same, fixed nothing.

Any idea about why may be happening?

Comment: Do you have `EventSystem` in your scene?

Comment: @Johnny I don't, the only objects that I've are that ones from the first picture in the post!

Comment: Add one to the root of the scene...

Comment: Totally! That was it! Any modification that I have to do? Post it as an answer pls

Comment: No, everything seems fine, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use UI elements, button for example, you need to add `EventSystem` to the scene. The scene should contain only one `EventSystem` and it could be anywhere in the hierarchy. Take a look at the official [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html).